# Rails 4 ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

How do you acces your asset pipeline using ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url in your views? I am using Rails 4. I need to access an image in app/assets/images.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to make sure that you have your configurations correct in your development.rb file.

1. Add this line to your config/environments/development.rb

-config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://yourwebsite.dev'

2. To access it from your views use this code.

   - <%= ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("your_image.png", type: :image) %>